# How do I delete a picture from an Imgur album?

Tags: imgur

I'm trying to delete a picture that I uploaded as part of a batch into an album. Can I delete one picture from it? If so, how do I do so?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you have an account on Imgur (which you should if you have an album), follow the instructions below:

**Desktop**: Begin from your account images page, which can be accessed by clicking your username in the top righthand corner while logged in.

[image]

Using your cursor, hover over the image, which will show a red 'x' in the lower righthand corner and an art palate in the lefthand corner. Clicking on the art palate will enable edit mode. Here you can rotate and resize images.

[image]

Clicking the 'x' will enable deletion mode. Click the art palate will enable edit mode.

[image]

Choose one or multiple images for removal. You can also click and drag over multiple images to select in large batches. Click delete or hide to complete that action.

If the image was uploaded anonymously you can use the deletion link provided on upload to delete it. You can also submit them to [http://imgur.com/removalrequest](https://imgur.com/removalrequest).

[Source](https://help.imgur.com/hc/en-us/articles/201484155).

Comment: The current imgur album page no longer looks like this, and I don't believe there's any way to delete an image (only rearrange it and change it's title/description it).

Comment: @Vadoff Yes, there is. See the updated instructions.